# MBR-partitioned HDD: How to encrypt Time Machine backup?

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, encryption

I'm giving my external HDD to a friend tomorrow for a few days. It's partitioned via Master Boot Record and there are two partitions: a NTFS partition and my Time Machine partition. I don't want him to be able to access the latter, but I can't turn the encryption on because the disk would have to be partitioned with GUID.

Changing the partition scheme would require me to reformat the disk. I can't do this either, as I don't have another HDD to put my files on in the meantime.

Is there another way to encrypt the partition, other than the built-in option of OS X?
Or is there a way to prohibit access to the Time Machine partition without any encryption at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you could do is creating a **encrypted disk image** on the external HDD and put your time maschine files in it for the timeframe your friend has the disk. To achieve this open the *disk utility* tool and choose *File -> New -> Blank Disc Image (or Image From Folder)*.

BUT keep in mind that as long as this disk is not (re-)formatted properly it will be easy to recover unencrypted data which seems to be deleted or moved (using some fancy recovery tools).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had to remove a bunch of old backups to free some space. Wow, this is really a chore with Time Machine.
No problem that the data could be recovered. I'm not assuming he would pry around in my stuff, it's a friend after all. I just don't like the feeling of anyone having full access to all my data.